# structuremap and Entity framework 4.1

Tags: model-view-controller, structuremap

I have my repository classes with the form like this:

```
  public partial class CategoryRepository : EfRepository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
{
    public CategoryRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    { }
}
public partial interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository<Category>
{
}
```

and i need to have many of them, same format. it's a long boring work to do. 
For bootstrapper, i use generic type scan.

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {              
            x.Scan(y =>
            {
                y.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IRepository<>));
                y.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>)).
                    OnAddedPluginTypes(z => z.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());

            });
```

Works just fine, but it'd be nicer if i dont need to declare all the repository classes like above. Anyway to get around this?? I'm using structuremap 2.6.2

THanks all,
Nam Vo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use generics for this. Declare a defaultrepository or something like this:

```
    public class DefaultRepository<TEntity> : 
EfRepository<TEntity>, IRepository<TEntity>
```

Make sure you constrain `TEntity` yourself to the proper types.